# How to set check marks for accessory when editing tableview?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to implement multi selection. but when I set tableview mode to editing, just delete accessory is shown for each row

### ViewDidLoad:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
self.myTableView.allowsMultipleSelection = true;
```

## set editing

This is called when I tap on edit navigation item.

```
(void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated

{
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
}
```

This makes tableview editable but just for delete. a delete button is shown in each row. but I want to show a selection mark button. like this:
[multi select picture](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiV-N7Lq8HdAhXSKVAKHWQrCoAQjRx6BAgBEAU&url=http%3A%2F%2Fblog.johnregner.com%2Fpost%2F138030831903%2Ftable-view-simple-multi-selection&psig=AOvVaw0Evw31HDpYeOnLLvpiFkng&ust=1537249711191291)

Comment: Have you added UITableViewCellSelectionStyle as none?

Comment: @RajeshDharani Yes sort of. selection is ok but I want to see other solutions too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We should set `allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing`. it is false by default.

```
self.myTableView.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = true;
```